# Как извлечь ссылки из логов апача?

Tags: apache

Есть стандартный лог апача. Лог просматривается удаленно по ssh. Нужно из всей массы текста получить ссылки, по которым происходят ошибки 403 и 404. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если лог апача - это файл log, то грепом по строчке ' 403 ' с последующим вырезанием нужных столбцов получаем требуемые ссылки:

```
grep ' 403 ' log | cut -d ' ' -f 7
```

если нужно избежать повторов (в логе могут многократно встречаться повторяющиеся ссылки), то вывод можно дополнительно пофильтровать:

```
grep ' 403 ' log | cut -d ' ' -f 7 | sort | uniq -c
```